# how long does account deletion requests usually take here?

Tags: discussion

I don't feel I am contributing anything here - 5 questions (only 2 upvoted/valued) and 1 reply (slammed in the comments - reply now deleted).

So, how log do deletion requests take?

Answer (score 2):

A few things to consider...

1. Question up votes are not always a sign of lack of value, it depends on who is in at the time and what their current interests are. Most of my questions accumulated votes well after I asked them.
2. Commentary isn't "slamming" and I read those comments, so I think you're probably being a little too sensitive there. Matt was stating his opinion/thoughts, but he did not apply a down vote which makes the "slam" idea even less so, since it's not as though he's going to miss the reputation effect.
3. Your answer has received a couple of up votes. That means, at least, that some portion of the membership agreed with you. The way I read it, you had 2 agree and one mildly disagree (since he didn't vote against) and that's caused you give it all up? Your choice there, but that seems pretty extreme.

Comment: I am embarrassed by my crap answer, and I have nothing really to contribute at all.

Comment: I didn't think it was a "crap answer"; it just didn't cover something important I thought needed to be in there, and so I brought it up.

Comment: @Damien: I think you might be taking things a little heavily. First, the point Joanne brought up about question votes is really very true...questions often don't get any votes at all at first, and sometimes never. Questions aren't really what need the votes here; answers are. As for commentary on answers...this is a very communal site. We discuss answers if their are inaccuracies or discrepancies to help keep the quality of content on **our** (as in, the community memberships...you included) site clean and valid. I think valid concerns were voiced, about *the content* of your answer...not you.

Comment: Also, when it comes to deleting an account...a couple things. First, a true "deletion" is not really possible...the accounts are StackExchange accounts, and they get linked to anything on StackExchange you use. Second, if we do "delete", its really a soft delete...your still there unless a higher up StackExchange admin actually "destroys" your account...and we reserve that for actual offenders who were trolling the site or otherwise being very disruptive with their activity...a category you don't remotely fit into. ;)

Comment: I encourage you to stick around. We are collaborative, so take comments and criticism as an attempt to help you, not an attempt to degrade you personally (because it really is the former.)

Comment: By the way, I really appreciate it when people point out problems with my own answers. The goal is perfect answers, but no one is perfect.

Comment: Agree with mattdm about commentary normally being to improve.  This is a used edited site where we try to help each other out and help make the best answers possible.  We have some people that are very knowledgeable and some that are just starting out and everybody has something to add.  We all often get suggestions of ways to improve posts.  It isn't something to be ashamed of, but rather just part of how the community works.  We'd hate to lose you and your input.